# Pass keyword argument to a macro in julia

Tags: macros, julia

I'd like to pass a keyword argument to a macro in julia. I try to parse the kwargs manually and build the Expr but got errors. Do I miss something?

```
macro sort(x, kv)
  @show x,kv
  d = []
  if kv.head == :(=)
    # push!(d, (kv.args[1], kv.args[2]))  # fail
    push!(d, (kv.args[1], esc(kv.args[2])))  # fail also
  end
  ex = quote
    sort($x; $(d...))
  end
  Meta.show_sexpr(ex)
  ex
end

x = collect(1:5)
rev=true
@sort x rev=rev
```

Output:

```
(x, kv) = (:x, :(rev = rev))
(:block,
  (:line, 9, Symbol("REPL[36]")),
  (:call, :sort, (:parameters, (:rev, :($(Expr(:escape, :rev))))), :x)
)ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (Expr) used in boolean context
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::Base.#kw##sort!)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#sort!, ::Array{Int64,1}) at ./<missing>:0
 [2] #sort#8(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Array{Int64,1}) at ./sort.jl:546
 [3] (::Base.#kw##sort)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#sort, ::Array{Int64,1}) at ./<missing>:0
 [4] macro expansion at ./REPL[36]:9 [inlined]
 [5] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

Edit: I am able to build keyword args using `:parameters` `Expr`. My generated `Expr` looks like the normal one. But strangely, I got the error "syntax: invalid syntax (parameters (kw (outerref rev) true))"

```
julia> macro m(f, x, ks...)
         @show f x ks
         ex = Expr(:call, f, x)
         par = Expr(:parameters )
         push!(ex.args, par)
         for kv∈ks
           k,v = kv.args
           push!(par.args, Expr(:kw, k, v))
         end
         Meta.show_sexpr(ex)
         ex
       end
@m (macro with 1 method)

julia>

julia> Meta.show_sexpr(:(sort(1:9; rev=true)))
(:call, :sort, (:parameters, (:kw, :rev, true)), (:(:), 1, 9))
julia> @m sort 1:9 rev=true
f = :sort
x = :(1:9)
ks = (:(rev = true),)
(:call, :sort, (:(:), 1, 9), (:parameters, (:kw, :rev, true)))ERROR: syntax: invalid syntax (parameters (kw (outerref rev) true))
```

Comment: If I declare only `ex = Expr(:call, f)`, and then `push!(ex.args, x)` after the kwargs loop, it works. Apparently that's what the next pass expects. I noticed this by looking at `x = @m sort 1:0 rev=true` `dump(x)` vs. `dump(:(sort, ...))`. (I guess one of the show functions was sorting kw args on display, so you weren't able to see the difference in the `show_sexpr` output).

Comment: Clever catch! Many thanks. Please re-post it as an answer so I can accept it.